# Easiest way to create arrays based on repeating character positions

Tags: arrays, matlab

I want to group my elements using the repeated segments in the array. The breaking is basically depend on where the repeated segments are, in my real data contains ~10000 elements and I want to know if there is a easier way to do that.

Here is a short example to clarify what I want:

Let's say I have an array,

```
A=[1 5 3 4 4 4 6 9 8 8 9 5 2];
```

What I want is to break `A` into `[1 5 3],[6 9], and [9 5 2];`

What is the easiest to code this using matlab??

Thanks.

Comment: Do you just want to avoid double entries? Or do you just want to split it up three-first-entries, tow-middle-entries, three-last-entries?

Comment: @ Rody, to fit my purpose best, it will be ideal to generate a 3 by 1 cell, cell 1-3 contains [1 5 3],[6,9],[9 5 2], respectively. Hope this clarify my question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For a vectorized solution, you can find out the places where either forward or backward differences to the neighbor are zero, and then use `bwlabel` (from the Image Processing Toolbox) and `accumarray` to gather the data.

```
A=[1 5 3 4 4 4 6 9 8 8 9 5 2];

d = diff(A)==0;
%# combine forward and backward difference
%# and invert to identify non-repeating elments
goodIdx = ~([d,false]|[false,d]);

%# create list of group labels using bwlabel
groupIdx = bwlabel(goodIdx);

%# distribute the data into cell arrays
%# note that the first to inputs should be n-by-1
B = accumarray(groupIdx(goodIdx)',A(goodIdx)',[],@(x){x})
```

**EDIT**

Replace the last two lines of code with the following if you want the repeating elements to appear in the cell array as well

```
 groupIdx = cumsum([1,abs(diff(goodIdx))]);
 B = accumarray(groupIdx',A',[],@(x){x})
```

**EDIT2**

If you want to be able to split consecutive groups of identical numbers as well, you need to calculate `groupIdx` as follows:

```
 groupIdx = cumsum([1,abs(diff(goodIdx))|~d.*~goodIdx(2:end)])
```

Comment: @ Jonas, just curious, is it possible to add the repeat elements to the cell array as well: [1 5 3] [4 4 4],[6 9],[8 8 8],[9 5 2]?

Comment: @ Jonas, I found if I use A=[1 2 3 4 4 5 5 6 6 6 7 8 9 8 6 5]; I will get B as [1;2;3], [4;4;5;5;6;6;6], [7;8;9;8;6;5]. Is it possible to break [4;4;5;5;6;6;6] in to [4;4],[5;5],[6;6;6]?

Answer (score 1):

Here is a solution that works if I understand the question correctly. It can probably be optimised further.

```
A=[1 5 3 4 4 4 6 9 8 8 9 5 2];

% //First get logical array of non consecutive numbers
x = [1 (diff(A)~=0)];
for nn=1:numel(A)
    if ~x(nn)
        if x(nn-1)            
            x(nn-1)=0;
        end
    end
end


% //Make a cell array using the logical array
y = 1+[0 cumsum(diff(find(x))~=1)];
x(x~=0) = y;
for kk = unique(y)
    B{kk} = A(x==kk);
end

B{:}
```

Comment: The top part where I make a logical array of non consecutive numbers would be a good place too look for a speed up. It still looks a bit ugly to me there